# How to add more information about authors with the Bibliography module?

Tags: users

We are setting up a **bibliography** for old and very rare resources with Drupal 7 and the [Bibliography](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio) module. We need to have more information about authors (picture, biography, nationality). We have seen that we could link authors to users but in our case authors don't require to have a real user account (because most of the time authors are dead).

My questions:

- How can we add **more information** to authors?
- Is it possible to **create** some kind of **user account** without login, password and e-mail ?
- Would it be possible to **create** a specific **content type** for authors (with fields for picture, biography and nationality) and link it to the biblio author, and in that case how could we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create another content type like "BookAuthor" with 1 node for each such Author. Then add fields to this content type for attributes such as picture, biography and nationality.

Assume you have a content type like "Ressources" (or just create one). Add a field in that content type using the [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module for it (probably with multiple values allowed). That way you can add one or more "links" in each Ressources-node to relevant nodes of type BookAuthor.

PS: just to avoid possible surprises, I would not call the content type "Author" (which has a special meaning in Drupal, so better to not confuse Drupal with the same name for your extra content type).

Comment: THanks for your answer. We are trying in that direction : create a author content type with entity reference to biblio author. And add an entity reference to the biblio content type to the author content type.